# How to find which websites a certain product belongs to?

Tags: magento2

A product can be enabled in several Magento websites. How can I get a list of these websites based on a product SKU?

Obviously, there is no `$product->getWebsites()`.

Looks like this information is in the table `catalog_product_website`, but I'd prefer solving this without direct SQL.

```
mysql> select * from catalog_product_website;
+------------+------------+
| product_id | website_id |
+------------+------------+
|          1 |          3 |
|          2 |          3 |
|          3 |          3 |
|          1 |          4 |
|          2 |          4 |
```

Comment: Have you tried `$product->getWebsiteIds()` ?

Comment: Yeah, that seems to do the trick!